# Is there a way to know the C++ objects count and their types of a running process?

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

The memory footprint of one of the processes that runs on Windows only is using more memory than before and I want to know which all C++ objects are in memory to see if there are extra allocations?
I can use WinDbg for .NET applications to find it out. But is it possible to do it for C++ without buying a memory profiler commercial application?

Comment: you should've expected to use commercial products the moment you started development on windows, anyway you should be able to port it to linux using wine and debug it with valgrind.

Comment: Try Visual Studio community edition. It is free and might be of help to you debugging on Windows: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy it is free for educational and research use, but commercial use has its hoops and gotchas.

Comment: @AhmedAEK actually, for individual use it IS now free.
"For individuals we recommend our free tools"
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing/?tab=individual

It costs for  "5 or more users/devices"
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing/?tab=business

Comment: Individual use ends when you have x people in the same building or your company start making money ... there are gotchas, it is not "free" software.

Comment: Sorry, @AhmedAEK, you are wrong about the "start making money" part. It IS free software. Review the license terms for individuals:
"Individual License. If you are an individual working on your own applications, either to sell or for any other purpose, you may use the software to develop and test those applications. "
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/vs2022-ga-community/

Comment: Tool recommendations are off topic here. But WinDbg still applies, DebugDiag has leak tracking rule, and there are other utilities to track native memory issues for your C++ programs. So, you can use search engines and AI to study them thoroughly before buying commercial profilers. But no doubt a commercial product offers integrated experience and is often worth the while.

Comment: IMHO, C++ does not maintain type information. Objects will be grouped by size.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot afford tools you might be able to use mixin code to add instance counting to each of your classes like this (you might want to output to a log file ofcourse). I am running out of time now so if you have questions ask them and I will get back to it later.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <string_view>

class report_instance_count_itf
{
public:
    virtual void report_construction(std::string_view type_name, std::size_t number_of_instances) const noexcept = 0;
    virtual void report_destruction(std::string_view type_name, std::size_t number_of_instances) const noexcept = 0;
};

class cout_reporter_t : public report_instance_count_itf
{
public:
    void report_construction(std::string_view type_name, std::size_t number_of_instances) const noexcept override
    {
        std::cout << "construct of class `" << type_name << "` number of instances = " << number_of_instances << "\n";
    }

    void report_destruction(std::string_view type_name, std::size_t number_of_instances) const noexcept override
    {
        std::cout << "destruction of class `" << type_name << "` number of instances = " << number_of_instances << "\n";
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// meyers singleton for now (ideally inject)
const report_instance_count_itf& get_instance_count_reporter()
{
    static cout_reporter_t reporter;
    return reporter;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Reusable instance counter implementation,
// make it a class template so we get a unique "instance" per
// class type that uses it. 
// put this class template in its own header file

template<typename class_t>
class instance_counter_impl_t
{
public:
    instance_counter_impl_t()
    {
        ++m_instance_count;
        const std::type_info& ti = typeid(class_t);
        get_instance_count_reporter().report_construction(ti.name(), m_instance_count);
    }

    ~instance_counter_impl_t()
    {
        --m_instance_count;
        const std::type_info& ti = typeid(class_t);
        get_instance_count_reporter().report_destruction(ti.name(), m_instance_count);
    }

    const auto instance_count() const noexcept
    {
        return m_instance_count;
    }

private:
    static std::atomic<std::size_t> m_instance_count;
};

template<typename class_t>
std::atomic<std::size_t> instance_counter_impl_t<class_t>::m_instance_count{};

// End of header file 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// inherit each class you want to count the number of instaces of
// from the class template specialized for that class. 
enter code here
class A :
    public instance_counter_impl_t<A>
{
};

class B :
    public instance_counter_impl_t<B>
{
};

int main()
{
    {
        A a1;
        B b1;
        A a2;
        B b2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```